# Matrices and eigenvalues

Tags: matrices, matrix-rank

Can there exist a 3x3 matrix which has only one eigenvalue? How is that possible for a 3x3 indicating all three variables are free variables?

Moreover, what is a rank of 3x3 matrix having 2 eigenvalues (2 same, 1 different) ?

Comment: The identity matrix has only one eigenvalue

Comment: @rrogerr It does not have ONE eigenvalue. It has THREE eigenvalues, with an algebraic multiplicity of 3.

Comment: @HenryTuring you win

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The identity matrix has its three eigenvalues equal to 1. That doesn't have to do with the independence of the variables because you can find three independent eigenvectors associated with the multiple eigenvalue.

A 3x3 matrix with exactly 2 equal eigenvalues can have rank equal to 1, 2 or 3.

Example rank = 1:

$$
        \begin{matrix}
        1 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 \\
        \end{matrix}
$$

Example rank = 2:

$$
        \begin{matrix}
        0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 2 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 2 \\
        \end{matrix}
$$

Example rank = 3:

$$
        \begin{matrix}
        1 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 2 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 2 \\
        \end{matrix}
$$

Comment: So even if an eigenvalue is repeated provided that it's not 0, the rank doesn't change?

Comment: No.... need to fill this with random stufffffffff

Comment: I think the confusion comes from the fact that when you change the base in which the matrix is expressed, its rank doesn't change... but if you change the eigenvalues of a matrix (for example by repeating an eigenvalue) then you are talking about a completely different matrix.

Comment: Does expressing a matrix in reduced Echoleon form changes the eigenvalues?

Comment: It may change them in scale. For example, if the first eigenvalue is 10, it can rescale it to 1 or -1. What doesn't chage is the amount of eigenvalues equal to zero.

Comment: So can the change in eigenvalue be calculated?

Comment: Ok, you have two matrices: one is the echelon form of the other. What's common? They have the same number of non zero eigenvalues. What changes? Probably, everything else: the absolute value and sign of each eigenvalue.

Comment: Okay thank you very much

Comment: Cheers! rrrrrrraaaaaannnnnnnndoooooommmmmmm stufffffff

Answer (score 0):

This is just a remark on rank-eigenvalue relation. First, denote the set of all $n\times n$ matrices with complex entries by $M_n(\mathbb{C})$. Let $A \in M_n(\mathbb{C})$ be given with $\mathrm{rank}(A) = r$. Then, $A$ has at most $r$ non-negative eigenvalues.

To see this, note two facts. First, one can identify $r$ linearly independent columns of $A$ such that every column of $A$ is a linear combination of these $r$ columns. Denote the matrix whose columns corresponds to these $r$ columns of $A$ as $X$ (hence, $X \in M_{n,r}(\mathbb{C})$). Now, $A=XY^{T}$ for some $Y \in M_{r,n}$. Then, an important theorem in linear algebra states that $AB$ and $BA$ has the same set of eigenvalues (with a possibility of additional zeroes in favor of $AB$ or $BA$). Hence, $A$ and $Y^{T}X \in M_r(\mathbb{C})$ has the same eigenvalues, with the addition of $n-r$ extra zeroes to the set of eigenvalues of $A$.

Hence, $\mathrm{rank}(A)=r$ implies that $A$ has at most $r$ non-negative eigenvalues.